# Same Index That Differs Only On INCLUDE-d Colums?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, ssms

I'm trying to optimize some database performance and I used the Estimated Execution Plan option in SSMS to have it recommend some indexes for me. Over a few hundred lines of code, it came back with suggestions like this:

**Index 1**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[TABLE_NAME] ([ColA])
INCLUDE ([ColB],[ColC])
```

**Index 2**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[TABLE_NAME] ([ColA])
INCLUDE ([ColB],[ColC],[ColD])
```

**Index 3**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[TABLE_NAME] ([ColA])
INCLUDE ([ColC],[ColD],[ColE])
```

I understand a little bit about the INCLUDE statement in SQL, but what I can't figure out is whether the index is only useful if your SELECT statement contains *all* the fields in the INCLUDE.

For instance, if I created just one index like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[TABLE_NAME] ([ColA])
INCLUDE ([ColB],[ColC],[ColD],[ColE])
```

would that cover all the scenarios covered by Indexes 1, 2, and 3 from SSMS, because all of them select some subset of those columns? Or would it be useless because none of them select columns B-E?

For what it's worth, the table has 36 fields in it, so it's not like this index would INCLUDE every record.

Thanks for any assistance/suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, creating an index with the union of all the columns suggested as included columns would be a good rule of thumb here, assuming all the queries analyzed are equally important to optimize, of course.

Comment: +1 to this. In addition it is possible for multiple indexes differing only in included columns to be useful but that is, as you say, rare.